# Css and jquery not loaded after call to ajax even when using .on to delegate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I'm loading some content via ajax when I click on a button and it works well though it doesn't load the css (bootstrap) for the new html content I added to an existing div.

I've tried everything and checked everywhere but other answers seem to say that the solution to my problem is to delegate my click call with .on but it doesn't work.

So here is the html code.

```
<button id="reloadtweet" class="btn btn-info mt-4 new">Reload to get new tweets</button>
<div id="newtweet" class="newt"></div>
```

Then the jquery code to load ajax on click:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('body').on('click', '#reloadtweet', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            reloadtweetb();
        })
    });
    </script>
```

And lastly the ajax bit:

```
    <script>

function reloadtweetb() {
console.log("reloadtweetb is working!");// sanity check
$.ajax({
    url : "/reloadtweet",
    type : "POST", // http method
    data : {    confnum : {{ confnum }},
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            }, // data sent with the post request

    // handle a successful response
    success : function(json) {

        if (json.success) {
            //alert('success');
            $('#newtweet').append('<p class="mt-3">See the last 15 tweets with the hashtag <b>#'+json.twitterwhashtag+'</b> over the last 7 days:</p>');
            $('#newtweet').append('<div class="row" align="center">');

            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < json.tweettext.length; i++) {

                $('#newtweet').append('<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mt-2 mb-2 d-flex align-items-stretch justify-content-center">');
                    $('#newtweet').append('<div class="card bg-light" style="width: 28rem;">');
                        $('#newtweet').append('<div class="card-body">');
                            $('#newtweet').append('<h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><a href="https://twitter.com/'+json.tweetscreenusers[i]+'" target="_blank" style="color: black;">'+ json.tweetusers[i]+'</a></h5>');
                                $('#newtweet').append('<small>'+ json.tweetdate[i]+' <br> Retweet count:'+ json.tweetretweetcount[i]+'<br> <a href="https://twitter.com/'+ json.tweetscreenusers[i]+'/status/'+ json.tweetid[i] +'" target="_blank">See on <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></small>');
                            $('#newtweet').append('<hr class="my-3" style="border-top: 2px dotted grey;">');
                            $('#newtweet').append('<p class="card-text" style="font-size: .9rem; font-weight: 400; color: #747373;">'+ json.tweettext[i]+'</p>');
                        $('#newtweet').append('</div>');
                        if(json.tweetimage[i]!='') {
                            $('#newtweet').append('<a href="https://twitter.com/'+json.tweetscreenusers[i]+'/status/'+ json.tweetid[i] +'/photo/1" target="_blank"><img class="card-img-top" src="'+ json.tweetimage[i] +'" height="200" alt="Organize a carbon-neutral conference"></a>');
                        }
                    $('#newtweet').append('</div>');
                $('#newtweet').append('</div>');

            }
            $('#newtweet').append('</div>');
 
        }else{
            alert('nada');
        }

        console.log("success"); // another sanity check
    },

    // handle a non-successful response
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
            " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
    }
});
};
</script>
```

It looks like this after the ajax call:

[after ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oggKH.png)

instead of like this:

[it should be like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbPLF.png)

Comment: where is your css ?

Comment: it is in the header of the html page.

Comment: or you mean in the code? I use bootstrap classes such as class="col-lg-4..., card-body, ... and it's like if they didn't exist after the ajax load but they load well without ajax.

Comment: You can't do `$('#newtweet').append('</div>');`, that's not how `.append()` works. Read the documentation of what it does again.

Comment: That's not just a random remark, that's why your code is not working. Look at the DOM this generates, it's not at all going to look like you expect. For generating complex HTML you might want to look into using a templating library such as [jquery-tmpl](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl), [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) or [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, I hadn't realised that! I used handlebars in the past and will do it again as I assume there is no easy jquery way of handling that?